# Can't figure out date time conversion from int to datetime

Tags: date, time

I have an application that stores date+time as int in a database.

### I would like to get back from the int to the real date&time!

I have these 2 examples:

919326588 ---> 25.03.2022 09:46
919322562 ---> 23.03.2022 14:43

I don't get it, even though I tried with julian days, unix-epoch, seconds from 1.1.1970, ....

Is there anybody out there who can help?

What I got so far is that the beginning is something like:
( 919362588 / 2000 ) + 2000000 --> 2459663.2939999998

The int part is the julian day 2022-03-24. The fraction part should be the fraction of a day in hours, minutes, ...

But it must be more than 0.5 to get over the 00:00 to 2022-03-25, but is only .2939999998 which is less than 0.5 .

assuming that the people dealing with these dates do not count from 12 - 12 but instead from 0 - 0 we have to add 0.5 to get from 12 - 0 midnight.

So this would mean:
0.2939999998 + 0+5 = 0.7939999998

**But is 2022-03-25 07:03:21 not 09:46 :-(**

Comment: Can you share more info about the database used?

Comment: You could start to see if the values are in minutes using: `select (919326588 - 919322562)/(24*60)` which gives `2.7958` When expected is 1.4 (because the last datetime is 1.4 days after the first datetime).  It would help to have more examples...

Comment: What I got so far is that the beginning is something like:
( 919362588 / 2000 ) + 2000000 --> 2459663.2939999998

The int part is the julian day 2022-03-24. The fraction part should be the fraction of a day in hours, minutes, ...

But it must be more than 0.5 to get over the 00:00 to 2022-03-25, but is only .2939999998 which is less than 0.5 .

assuming that the people dealing with these dates do not count from 12 - 12 but instead from 0 - 0 we have to add 0.5 to get from 12 - 0 midnight.

So this would mean:
0.2939999998 + 0+5 = 0.7939999998

But is 2022-03-25 07:03:21 not 09:46

Comment: The database is postgresql

Comment: Can you add data to your database? And check wat value is returned when you enter `0` in that date field?  Or when you enter a datetime like `'2022-03-30 00:00:00'` and `'2022-03-29 00:00:00'`, just to check the difference between those 2 values (and focus on date first, and time later....)